# Несколько изображений в html в telegra.ph

Tags: html, python, изображения

Нужно перепарсить вк-пост в telegra.ph. Для этого сначала надо засунуть всё в html, точнее подобие html. К сожалению, есть проблемы с изображениями. Должен быть этот пост [ссылка](http://vk.com/wall-31480508_343818). Вот что получается [ссылка](http://telegra.ph/Post-iz-pikabu-Sejchas-by-v-derevnyu-Avtor-06-29-7).
Вот какой код:

```
<p>Дата публикации Wed Jun 28 10:00:26 2017

Сейчас бы в деревню... 

Автор: BirdBorn
Комментарии: pikabu.ru/story/_5154703 </p>
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c637726/v637726165/622fe/SzmD7-VoABA.jpg" alt="SzmD7-VoABA.jpg" width="50%" height="50%">
<br>
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c637726/v637726165/62308/CPgkpk414Mk.jpg" alt="CPgkpk414Mk.jpg" width="50%" height="50%">
<br>
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c637726/v637726165/62312/kStJc5QMRpE.jpg" alt="kStJc5QMRpE.jpg" width="50%" height="50%">
<br>
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c637726/v637726165/6231c/M1rGntA8Y58.jpg" alt="M1rGntA8Y58.jpg" width="50%" height="50%">
<br>
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c637726/v637726165/62326/X3O8MDpwDJY.jpg" alt="X3O8MDpwDJY.jpg" width="50%" height="50%">
<br>
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c637726/v637726165/62330/xLUvVQ19SIo.jpg" alt="xLUvVQ19SIo.jpg" width="50%" height="50%">
<br>
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c637726/v637726165/6233a/CubQCoGViT4.jpg" alt="CubQCoGViT4.jpg" width="50%" height="50%">
<br>
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c637726/v637726165/62344/7pBIOJPpPrg.jpg" alt="7pBIOJPpPrg.jpg" width="50%" height="50%">
<br>
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c637726/v637726165/6234b/lHjAzDnl4Gk.jpg" alt="lHjAzDnl4Gk.jpg" width="50%" height="50%">
<br>
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c637726/v637726165/62355/-TgR1UZosf8.jpg" alt="-TgR1UZosf8.jpg" width="50%" height="50%">

Оригинал поста vk.com/wall-31480508_343818
```

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы отображалось больше изображений

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ух. Долго мучался, просматривал множество сайтов.
Проблема оказалось простой.
Взгляните на строчку с картинкой

```
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c637726/v637726165/622fe/SzmD7-VoABA.jpg" alt="SzmD7-VoABA.jpg" width="50%" height="50%">
```

Если присмотреться, то видно, что я просто косой олыфваоыфлр и не поставил `/` перед `>`
Получается, что `<img>` вообще еще не заканчивался. 
Буду благодарен, если объяснят, почему это вообще работает, а не выдаёт ошибку